# What is wrong with the testers?

Tags: dictionary, triggers, boolean, feed

The code is supposed to return Trigger Objects - length of the Trigger map should show the actual number of triggers that there actually are...it should be returning True if there is at least one or more trigger but they are ALL returning FALSE with ZERO triggers...can anyone please help out? the code is below and the error messages from the testers will be printed below that.

```
def makeTrigger(triggerMap, triggerType, params, name):

    def readTriggerConfig(filename):
        triggerfile = open(filename, "r")
        all = [ line.rstrip() for line in triggerfile.readlines() ]
        lines = []
        for line in all:
            if len(line) == 0 or line[0] == '#':
                continue
            lines.append(line)
            if len(line) >= 1:
                return True
        triggers = []
        triggerMap = {}

    # Be sure you understand this code - we've written it for you,
    # but it's code you should be able to write yourself
        for line in lines:

            linesplit = line.split(" ")

        # Making a new trigger
            if linesplit[0] != "ADD":
                trigger = makeTrigger(triggerMap, linesplit[1],
                                      linesplit[2:], linesplit[0])

        # Add the triggers to the list
            else:
                for name in linesplit[1:]:
                    triggers.append(triggerMap[name])

        return triggers

import thread

SLEEPTIME = 60 #seconds -- how often we poll

def main_thread(master):

    try:
        # These will probably generate a few hits...
        t1 = TitleTrigger("Obama")
        t2 = SubjectTrigger("Romney")
        t3 = PhraseTrigger("Election")
        t4 = OrTrigger(t2, t3)
        triggerlist = [t1, t4]

        # TODO: Problem 11
        # After implementing makeTrigger, uncomment the line below:
        triggerlist = readTriggerConfig("triggers.txt")

        # from here is about drawing

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

        t = "Google & Yahoo Top News"
        title = StringVar()
        title.set(t)
        ttl = Label(master, textvariable=title, font=("Helvetica", 18))
        ttl.pack(side=TOP)
        cont = Text(master, font=("Helvetica",14), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        cont.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        cont.tag_config("title", justify='center')
        button = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
        button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        guidShown = []
        def get_cont(newstory):
            if newstory.getGuid() not in guidShown:
                cont.insert(END, newstory.getTitle()+"\n", "title")
                cont.insert(END, (80 * '-').join("\n\n"), "title")
                cont.insert(END, newstory.getSummary())
                cont.insert(END, (120 * '*').join("\n\n"), "title")
                guidShown.append(newstory.getGuid())

        while True:

            print "Polling . . .",
            Get stories from Google's Top Stories RSS news feed
            stories = process("http://news.google.com/?output=rss")

            Get stories from Yahoo's Top Stories RSS news feed
            stories.extend(process("http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories"))

            stories = filterStories(stories, triggerlist)

            map(get_cont, stories)
            scrollbar.config(command=cont.yview)


            print "Sleeping..."
            time.sleep(SLEEPTIME)

    except Exception as e:
        print e


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Some RSS parser")
    thread.start_new_thread(main_thread, (root,))
    root.mainloop()
```

Now here are the error messages from the testers - please help out if possible...it has my mind all muddled up!!! There are SEVEN tests in Total that are giving these error messages and I am still clueless as to how I can fixem up! Please help if you can...ciao!

```
Test: 1 make TitleTrigger
Your output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE NASA

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
None
**** ERROR: It looks like your makeTrigger function is not properly returning the     trigger; the trigger, rather than 'None', should not have printed on the previous line.
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  False
**** ERROR: Length of triggerMap should be 1; it is:  0
Correct output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE NASA

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
TitleTrigger made with word: NASA
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  True

Test: 2 make basic triggers
Your output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE NASA
t2 SUBJECT Mars
t3 SUMMARY rocket

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
None
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  False
**** ERROR: Length of triggerMap should be 3; it is:  0
Correct output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE NASA
t2 SUBJECT Mars
t3 SUMMARY rocket

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
TitleTrigger made with word: NASA
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  True
SubjectTrigger made with word: Mars
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  True
SummaryTrigger made with word: rocket
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  True
Test: 3 make PhraseTriggers
Your output:
Trigger file:
t1 PHRASE NASA
t2 PHRASE Curiosity Mars rover
t3 PHRASE Neil deGrasse Tyson

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
None
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  False
**** ERROR: Length of triggerMap should be 3; it is:  0
Correct output:
Trigger file:
t1 PHRASE NASA
t2 PHRASE Curiosity Mars rover
t3 PHRASE Neil deGrasse Tyson

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
PhraseTrigger made with phrase: NASA
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  True
PhraseTrigger made with phrase: Curiosity Mars rover
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  True
PhraseTrigger made with phrase: Neil deGrasse Tyson
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  True
Test: 4 make NotTriggers
Your output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE Manitoba
t2 NOT t1
t3 PHRASE British Colombia
t4 NOT t3

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
None
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t4 in triggerMap?  False
**** ERROR: Length of triggerMap should be 4; it is:  0
Correct output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE Manitoba
t2 NOT t1
t3 PHRASE British Colombia
t4 NOT t3

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
TitleTrigger made with word: Manitoba
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  True
NotTrigger made with trigger: TitleTrigger("Manitoba")
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  True
PhraseTrigger made with phrase: British Colombia
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  True
NotTrigger made with trigger: PhraseTrigger("British Colombia")
 --> Is trigger t4 in triggerMap?  True
Test: 5 make AndTriggers
Your output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE Manitoba
t2 PHRASE British Colombia
t3 AND t1 t2

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
None
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  False
**** ERROR: Length of triggerMap should be 3; it is:  0
Correct output:
Trigger file:
t1 TITLE Manitoba
t2 PHRASE British Colombia
t3 AND t1 t2

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
TitleTrigger made with word: Manitoba
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  True
PhraseTrigger made with phrase: British Colombia
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  True
AndTrigger made with triggers: TitleTrigger("Manitoba") and PhraseTrigger("British Colombia")
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  True
Test: 6 make OrTriggers
Your output:
Trigger file:
t1 SUBJECT Harper
t2 PHRASE Prime Minister
t3 OR t1 t2

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
None
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  False
**** ERROR: Length of triggerMap should be 3; it is:  0
Correct output:
Trigger file:
t1 SUBJECT Harper
t2 PHRASE Prime Minister
t3 OR t1 t2

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
SubjectTrigger made with word: Harper
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  True
PhraseTrigger made with phrase: Prime Minister
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  True
OrTrigger made with triggers: SubjectTrigger("Harper") and PhraseTrigger("Prime Minister")
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  True
Test: 7 make composite triggers
Your output:
Trigger file:
t1 SUBJECT Cameron
t2 SUBJECT Gillard
t3 SUBJECT Harper
t4 PHRASE Prime Minister
t5 AND t1 t4
t6 AND t2 t4
t7 OR t3 t4

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
None
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t4 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t5 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t6 in triggerMap?  False
None
 --> Is trigger t7 in triggerMap?  False
**** ERROR: Length of triggerMap should be 7; it is:  0
Correct output:
Trigger file:
t1 SUBJECT Cameron
t2 SUBJECT Gillard
t3 SUBJECT Harper
t4 PHRASE Prime Minister
t5 AND t1 t4
t6 AND t2 t4
t7 OR t3 t4

**** RUNNING MAKETRIGGER ON TRIGGER FILE ****
SubjectTrigger made with word: Cameron
 --> Is trigger t1 in triggerMap?  True
SubjectTrigger made with word: Gillard
 --> Is trigger t2 in triggerMap?  True
SubjectTrigger made with word: Harper
 --> Is trigger t3 in triggerMap?  True
PhraseTrigger made with phrase: Prime Minister
 --> Is trigger t4 in triggerMap?  True
AndTrigger made with triggers: SubjectTrigger("Cameron") and PhraseTrigger("Prime Minister")
 --> Is trigger t5 in triggerMap?  True
AndTrigger made with triggers: SubjectTrigger("Gillard") and PhraseTrigger("Prime Minister")
 --> Is trigger t6 in triggerMap?  True
OrTrigger made with triggers: SubjectTrigger("Harper") and PhraseTrigger("Prime Minister")
 --> Is trigger t7 in triggerMap?  True
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't ever executing any code inside the makeTrigger function; you are only defining another function, readTriggerConfig.

Have you attempted to isolate the makeTrigger function from the rest of the code and run it with a small set of known inputs to get a better idea of its behavior?  Stepping through its execution with a debugger might help you understand what is happening as well.